# MySQL - Group by with 2 conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need some advice with a Select: I need to sum an amount by employee and month. With a Group by I am able to select the Month - the amount will be summed - but not by employee but by month:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(datum) AS Monat,ID AS id, STATUS AS STATUS, MA AS Mitarbeiter,SUM(preis) AS Preis 
FROM wccrm_prov 
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(datum)
```

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a crosstab query. In this [post](http://evolt.org/node/26896/) you'll find a good example (ignore the Excel portions).

Comment: `GROUP BY MONTHNAME(datum), Mitarbeiter`?

Comment: I think just using both fields in the group by would work; assuming id is the employee id, just do GROUP BY Id,Monthname(datum)

Comment: Why are you guys posting comments instead of answers? It prevents accepting and upvoting, thus subverting the system and helping no one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be similar to

```
SELECT 
  MONTHNAME(datum) AS Monat
  , EMPLOYEE
  ,ID AS id
  ,STATUS AS STATUS
  ,MA AS Mitarbeiter
  ,SUM(preis) AS Preis 
FROM wccrm_prov 
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(datum), EMPLOYEE
```

I used a new field EMPLOYEE, as I'm not familiar with your non-english language used in the question query text.  You can obviously swap this with your Employee field

Comment: Dear Grantly, thanks a lot - works like a charm :-) Now I have to add a "order by", but I think I have to do it with a JOIN - or?

Comment: Oh - it was quite easy:

SELECT MONTHNAME( datum ) AS Monat, ID AS id, 
STATUS AS 
STATUS , MA AS Mitarbeiter, SUM( preis ) AS Preis
FROM wccrm_prov
GROUP BY MONTHNAME( datum ) , MA
ORDER BY Datum ASC

Comment: @bosstone no problem. That looks fine. The order by uses ASC by default so you can leave that off if you like